# Accessing a collection item using a key

Tags: c#, collections

I've declared a list to create my class object dynamically.

```
List<clsFormula> oFormula = new List<clsFormula>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  oFormula.Add(new clsFormula());
}
```

When I want to use the function from object number 2 I will write my code like

```
oFormula[2].FunctioName();
```

My question is: Can I define a name directly into the object instead of using number ? so it would be like `oFormula["StringName"].FunctionName()`; what kind of code i should use when i am declaring the runtime object?

Comment: you can try use a `Dictionary<string,clsFormula>` instead of using a `list<clsFormula>`

Comment: It is workable~!
'Dictionary<string, clsFormula> of = new Dictionary<string, clsFormula>();
of.Add("Plus", new clsFormula());
MessageBox.Show(of["Plus"].Operate("+", 1, 2).ToString());'

Comment: Yes, however you need to know the name of the item at the point of inserting it into the dictionary. KeyedCollection encapsulates this into the collection itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new collection type and inherit it from System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection. Override the GetKeyForItem method and return the name of the clsFormula object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx

```
public class clsFormulaCollection : KeyedCollection<string, clsFormula>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(clsFormula item)
    {
        return item.Name;
    }
}

clsFormulaCollection oFormula = new clsFormulaCollection();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    oFormula.Add(new clsFormula());
}

oFormula["FormulaName"].SomeFunction();
```

Comment: i am using Framework3.5 i think KeyCollection workable for framework4.0 only.

Comment: KeyedCollection has been available since .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

*Realize that its not java, but as I reached delete limit leaving it open.*

---

If its java.

[`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) holds data and map it with index. for your requirement you need to use [`java.util.Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
Map<String, clsForumla> map = new Map<String, clsForumla>();
map.put("firstObj",new clsForumla());
map.put("secondObj",new clsForumla());
map.put("thirdObj",new clsForumla());


//calling method on second object

map.get("secondObj").foo();
```

Comment: It's not Java, because he called "Add".  Starting method names with a capital letter is more of a Microsoft thing.

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine for me,

i have created a sample application for your solution,

i have a class as below,

```
public class ClsFormula
{
    public ClsFormula()
    {

    }

    public int Function1()
    {
        return 5 + 6;
    }
}
```

now i use this class for one of the click event, making list of the class object,

```
List<ClsFormula> clsformula = new List<ClsFormula>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
        {
            ClsFormula objcls = new ClsFormula();
            clsformula.Add(objcls);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(clsformula[2].Function1().ToString());
```

it works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

List doesn't have an indexer which uses a string parameter. You can inherit from `List<T>` and create an Indexer which accepts string and you need to implement the logic to find and return the item.

```
public class SampleList<T> : List<T>
{
public T this(string name)
{
get
{
//Find the Item and return.
}
}
}
```